# satellizer redirectUri not working after successfull auth

Tags: angularjs, facebook-authentication, satellizer

I have implemented facebook authentication using angular js for the fronted and laravel for the backend though everything else work fine a get the token from facebook but satellizer doesnot redirect to the redirectUri on success.

below is my code

```
       $authProvider.facebook({
        clientId:'xxxxxxx',
        url: config.api.protocol + '://' + config.api.host + config.api.path + 'auth/facebook',
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/dashboard/home'
       })
```

Answer (score -1):

you should give the redirect URI as below
redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/'

it works fine for me